# Connecting MS SQL Server with mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component, mule-module-jpa

I am working in a mule application and I am new in mule application development. 
In my application, how can I connect to MS Sql server.
I have tried Database connector but it is not having Connection configuration for SQL Server.

Thanks.

Comment: check page roytuts.com/mule-jdbc-insert-example/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using SQLserver express 2012.
- Download the sqljdbc41.jar file from microsoft [sqljdbc41.jar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774)
- Put the jar file into the Anypoint Studio Plugin directory (e.g C:\Program Files (x86)\AnypointStudio\plugins)
- Using SQL configuration manager, goto SQL Server Network Configuration --> Protocols for SQLEXPRESS and enable TCP/IP protocol

In AnyPoint studio (I'm using v5.1 March 2015), select the Database connector.
In the General Tab --> Basic Settings, edit the connector configuration.

set the Datbase URL:

jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS;database=your_database;user=your_dbuser;password=your_dbPassword

set the Driver Class to

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

and press "Test Connection"

Comment: In addition to this, I had to manually add the reference to the sqljdbcXX.jar on the project libraries

Answer (score 0):

You must create a connection string to connect  your application to SQL server.
Like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can connect MS SQL with Mule 3.5 :-
Take this example :-

```
<db:generic-config name="Generic_Database_Configuration" url="jdbc:sqlserver://<your servername>:1433;databaseName=<your DB name>;user=<user name>;password=<password>"
        driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        doc:name="Generic Database Configuration" />

<flow name="BestelItems" doc:name="BestelItems">
 <poll doc:name="Poll">
 <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="30" timeUnit="SECONDS"/>
  <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
  <db:select config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
      <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[select * from table1 where ID=8]]>
  </db:dynamic-query>
 </db:select>
</processor-chain>
</poll><logger message="Payload :- #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
</flow>
```

For older Mule version (Mule 3.4 or before):-
Please follow the example :-

```
<jdbc-ee:mssql-data-source name="MS_SQL_Data_Source" url="jdbc:sqlserver://<your servername>:1433;databaseName=<your DB name>;user=<user name>;password=<password>" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="MS SQL Data Source"/>

<jdbc-ee:connector name="Database_Global" dataSource-ref="MS_SQL_Data_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database" transactionPerMessage="false">
 <jdbc-ee:query key="RetriveQuery" value="Select * from table1"/> 
</jdbc-ee:connector>

  <flow name="InboundJDBC" doc:name="InboundJDBC" initialState="stopped">
  <jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint  queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="1000" doc:name="Database"   connector-ref="Database_Global" queryKey="RetriveQuery">
  <jdbc-ee:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" />
     <property key="receiveMessageInTransaction" value="true"/>
  </jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint>
  <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
  <logger message="JDBC Transaction #[message.payload] **************" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
  </flow>
```